# Are any Classical Hebrew translations of the New Testament based on ancient languages other than Koine Greek?

Tags: bible-translation, new-testament, hebrew

There seem to be many Hebrew translations of the New Testament, both Classical and Modern.

However, most of these seem to be based on some form of the Koine Greek New Testament (whether it be the Textus receptus, or the majority text, or one of the critical editions)

I was wondering if any (specifically Classical) Hebrew translations of the New Testament, in whole or in part, have been made based on other ancient versions (for example, the Peshitta or the Vulgate)

To clarify,

1. Yes, I am aware that the Vulgate and other ancient versions were translated from Koine Greek but are different from any edition of the Greek New Testament available today, since they were probably based on Greek manuscripts that are now lost
2. Yes, I am aware that the general consensus is that the Peshitta was translated from Greek to Aramaic, although a minority of authors (like George Lamsa) have attempted to argue that the reverse is true
3. Yes, I am aware that there are other ancient translations besides the Vulgate and the Peshitta. I just gave these 2 as examples, and would really be interested in ANY Classical Hebrew translation of the New Testament (or part thereof) based on a non-Greek ancient version

Comment: The Peshitta and the Vulgate are translations from the original Koine Greek text. They are called 'versions'. So, you are asking if any extant Hebrew translations were made from these two versions which were, in turn, translated out of the original Koine Greek autographs.

Comment: biblical hermeneutics might be a better place...or meta

Answer (score 2):

There is a Hebrew version of the Gospel of Matthew that some believe comes from the original Hebrew text that was later translated into the Greek text we have today. You can read about the evidences within the text for this from authors such as Nehemia Gordon and George Howard.

[Shem Tob's Hebrew Matthew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem_Tob%27s_Hebrew_Gospel_of_Matthew):
From Wikipedia

> Shem Tob's Hebrew Gospel of Matthew is the oldest extant Hebrew version of the Gospel of Matthew. It was included in the 14th-century work Eben Boḥan (The Touchstone)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem_Tob%27s_Hebrew_Gospel_of_Matthew) by the Spanish Jewish Rabbi Shem-Tov ben Isaac ben Shaprut. George Howard[2] has argued that Shem Tov's Matthew comes from a much earlier Hebrew text that was later translated into Greek and other languages. A characteristic feature of this Hebrew gospel is the appearance in 20 places of השם (HaShem, "the Name"), in the abbreviated form ה״, where the Gospel of Matthew has Κύριος ("the Lord").